Removing extension on some pages
I have a working htaccess to remove the extension on some pages and its working. But the problem files in other folder like /blog/ don't work.
I want also files in other folders to be removed.
RewriteEngine On

# Remove .php extension for specific pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index|contact)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(index|contact)$ /$1.php [L]

# Redirect requests for .php files to extension-less URLs for specific pages
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index|contact)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index|contact)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]


Remove the start of line char ^ and adapt to your needs or include /blog/ and make it optional.

@-Markus Zeller How?

^(index|contact)$ is a regular expression. Also see chapter https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

there many lines with ^(index|contact)$. so i should remove ^ anywhere it starts with ^(index|contact)$

Never just blindly do something you read somewhere. You need to understand the tools you are using. That includes reading the actual documentation, just as it has been recommended to you. And by making experiments to understand the details. We all did. That is how we learned.
